Creating a dynamic module on nestjs
I defined a module with some classes and in one of them I need to retrieve an injected parameter.
I have a method who receives this parameter, and on this method I would like to create the module, injecting this parameter, is it possible?
I have tried some different approaches:
import {DynamicModule, Inject, Injectable, Module} from '@nestjs/common';
import {ModuleRef} from '@nestjs/core';

@Injectable()
export class Client {
  constructor(@Inject('company') private readonly company: string) {}

  async handle(payload: any): Promise<void> {
    console.log(`Handle payload ${payload} for company ${this.company}`);
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class Service {
  constructor(private readonly clientService: Client) {}

  async handle(payload: any): Promise<void> {
    this.clientService.handle(payload);
  }
}

const config = {
  imports: [],
  providers: [Client, Service],
  exports: [Service]
};

@Module(config)
export class MyModule {
  static register(company?: string): DynamicModule {
    return {
      ...config,
      module: MyModule,
      providers: [
        ...config.providers,
        {
          provide: 'company',
          useValue: company
        }
      ]
    };
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class HandlerService {
  constructor(private readonly moduleRef: ModuleRef) {}

  protected async handle(company: string, payload: any): Promise<void> {
    const module = MyModule.register(company);
    // this part breaks
    const service = await this.moduleRef.resolve(Service, module.module);
    await service.handle(payload);
  }
}


The resolve function accepts a context-id as the second argument. Please follow these links for dynamic modules: https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/dynamic-modules, and for dynamic resolving https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/module-ref
